# Typing the returned value of a store selector function with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a store function. I am trying to make a selector function so I can only select a portion of the store and return it. Here is a very stripped down version of what I have.

Playground [Sandbox Code](https://playcode.io/1614095)

```
type Listener<TStore> = {
   selectorFn: (store: TStore) => TStore
}

function createStore<TStore>(store: TStore) {
    const listeners = new Set<Listener<TStore>>()

    function useStore<T>(selectorFn = (store: TStore) => store): T {
        // this will be added to the listeners set but that code is not relevant
        const listener = {
            selectorFn,
            //some other stuff
        }

        return selectorFn(store)
    }

    return [useStore]
}

const [useStore] = createStore<{count: number, input: string}>({
    count: 0,
    input: ''
})

function DisplayStore() {
    const count = useStore((store) => store.count )
}
```

Here I am running into the issue of the error in the Display function `Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ count: number; input: string; }'.`

So then I tried to add a generic to the useStore function like so:

```
function useStore<T>(selectorFn = (store: TStore) => store): T {
    return selectorFn(store)
}
```

Then on the return of the useStore function I get `'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TStore'.` I also need the listener to satisfy that type as well so I'm not sure how well generics will work here.

How would I type this so I in the `DisplayStore` function I can correctly type the returned value of the selector function? Working code blocked by typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use overloads

```
function createStore<TStore>(store: TStore) {
    function useStore(): TStore;
    function useStore<T>(selectorFn: (store: TStore) => T): T;
    function useStore<T>(selectorFn?: (store: TStore) => T) {
        return selectorFn ? selectorFn(store) : store;
    }

    return [useStore]
}
```

(this still won't allow to assign the default argument tho)

Answer (score 0):

your issue is how you define `selectorFn` in `type Listener`.

```
selectorFn: (store: TStore) => TStore
```

You say it's a function that receives a `TStore` and also returns a `TStore`. You need to allow a different return type.

```
type Listener<TStore, TReturn> = {
   selectorFn: (store: TStore) => TReturn
}

function createStore<TStore>(store: TStore) {
  const listeners = new Set<Listener<TStore, unknown>>();
  
  // from Dimava: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77212544/6567275
  function useStore():TStore;
  function useStore<T>(selectorFn: (store: TStore) => T): T {
  function useStore<T>(selectorFn?:(store: TStore) => T) {
    // ...
    return selectorFn ? selectorFn(store) : store;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: No the createStore is just a factory function that returns some functions so you can use, set and get the store value. This is for React btw. The listener is an object of the selectorFn and an updater function. The listener will not and cannot hold the store value because it will always be wrong as the listener is used in the setstore function that is not listed in the example because it is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Nothing here holds anything. this is just typing. What types go in, what type come out. And your mistake is that **you define** for the `selectorFn`  that it has to come out the same type as goes in. Therefore *by your (type) definition* it can not return anything but the entire store. **that's** what you need to change, this type definition; that something different may come out of `selectorFn` than what goes in.

Comment: I still get the same error as before in the second part of the  quesiton at the return statement.  `'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TStore'.  This type parameter might need an `extends T` constraint` https://playcode.io/1614095

Comment: @user3331344 yes, my oversight. [Dimava had answered that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77212544/6567275). I've updated my answer with his changes.